# Please help me understand 言えば

Tags: translation, word-usage, conditionals

I'm struggling to understand what 言えば in a question. The sentence is:

> お前ら 何度言えば分かるんだ

I understand the general idea of what is being said, but I don't know which part 言えば relates to and I'm feeling rather confused.

Please can you help me understand / translate the sentence

Comment: Please give your own translation so potential answerers can see how much you already understand.

Comment: It would also help if you include a bit more of the conversation, so we can understand the context more.

Answer (score 5):

Try breaking it down, note there is an implicit question in this sentence:

分かるんだ - (You) understand (it)

言えば分かるんだ - If I say it, you will understand

何度言えば分かるんだ - How many times if it is said, will you understand  ->> How many times do I have to say it until you understand

お前ら 何度言えば分かるんだ - You guys, how many times do I have to say it until you understand?